# `watch` a PostgreSQL query without displaying the full connection string

Tags: debian, ubuntu, watch

I'd like to share online, with team members, some live modifications on a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database (hosted on a dockerized Debian Bullseye) using `watch` (if you know any other tool, preferably [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) but I wasn't able to figure out a way of watching to live modifications with it, please let me know).

For the moment I'm doing it as follow:

```bsh
$  PGPASSWORD=***************
$ reset
$ watch -n 1.0 "psql \
-d postgresql://postgres:${PGPASSWORD}@localhost:5432/dbname \
  -c 'select id,name,customer,order,product from public.table where id in (1,2,3,4) order by (id)';"
```

so that the password is not stored in the bash history (please notice the white space in front of the first line) and it is no more visible on screen after the call to `reset` (the host machine is on Ubuntu 18.04).

But when the `watch` command starts, it actually displays the "translation" of the full connection query string into plain text at the very top of the screen, therefore displaying the database password (or any other variables):

```bsh
Every 1.0s: psql -d postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:5439/dbname -c (...)
...
```

Is there any chance of hiding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, use the `-t` option, which, as stated by the doc: `turn off header`.

This will only print the output of the called command.

More info:

```
$ watch --help

Usage:
 watch [options] command

Options:
  -b, --beep             beep if command has a non-zero exit
  -c, --color            interpret ANSI color and style sequences
  -d, --differences[=<permanent>]
                         highlight changes between updates
  -e, --errexit          exit if command has a non-zero exit
  -g, --chgexit          exit when output from command changes
  -n, --interval <secs>  seconds to wait between updates
  -p, --precise          attempt run command in precise intervals
  -t, --no-title         turn off header
  -x, --exec             pass command to exec instead of "sh -c"

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -v, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see watch(1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/libpq-pgpass.html)?
It's much safer I think.